# Plotting binary covariate responses in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with binary (0 or 1) indicator columns like `"age_30_35", "age_36_40"`, etc. For example a person of age 36 would have `( age_30_35=0, age_36_40=1 )`. Also, there is a reference category `(age_30_35=0, age_36_40=0)`. Here's an example:

```
data<- data.frame(c(1,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(2.5,1.3,4.5))
colnames(data)=c('age_30_35','age_36_40','muscle_strength')
```

I want to make some plots of how each category affects a continuous response variable "muscle_strength." For example, box plots for each group: reference category, `age_30_35`, `age_36_40`. I know how to do it if I were to make an extra factor column with indicators 1,2,3 representing each group. What's the most painless way of doing this without actually creating the extra factor? In particular, I'd like a solution that easily scales to many columns.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to "reshape" your datasets from wide to long.  If so, there's lots of info out there on this topic if you search "r reshape wide to long".

Comment: @aosmith: Thanks for the suggestion, that should probably work. I'm hoping for a quicker solution though, perhaps as an option in ggplot?

Comment: I suspect that the most painless way to do this is either to reshape the data (as suggested by aosmith)  or else actually to create the extra factor.  Why don't you want to do either of these? Note that either option could easily scale to a large number of columns (you certainly wouldn't create the new factor by hand!)
Otherwise, you'll end up writing a script that effectively subsets the data **exactly like the factor would**, and then generates your plots one-by-one from different data subsets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create the extra `factor` by:

```
i <- 1:2 #indices of columns with dummies 
f <- factor(
    as.matrix(data[,i]) %*% 1:length(i), 
    labels=c("ref", names(data[,i]))
)
boxplot(data$muscle_strength ~ f)
```